# How to import md5 salt passwords from symfony to laravel 4

Tags: symfony, laravel, md5, laravel-4, sha1

The user table from the old symfony system has the following columns:

```
email               | algorithm   | salt                              | password
--------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-------------
techytimo@gmail.com | sha1        | ea579e44dd150e5ba6680d6a3cee26b4  | f48598ad17acf18583d8499d7c6abc430929ae49
```

The new system i created with laravel 4 has the following columns:

```
email               | password
--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
techytimo@gmail.com | $2y$08$Zz3rVIW4qJFd5IdTfzpw3OrH0HxGO8BrBxfonIQCvU33/yWQkUAe
```

How do i import the 3000 accounts with their passwords from the old system to the new system without having the users to register again?

Also a way to encrypt my passwords with laravel 4 in the same format would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround is to extends Auth module in Laravel, to implement your hash solution from Symfony.
Rewriting `Auth::attempt()`, hashing your password the way you want to, will work.
Same for `Hash::X`, you have to rewrite a function in your `Auth` class to hash new users password same way.

---

How you can implement your hash method :

Create a library in a folder name **libraries** into **app**, then, create your **ServiceProvider** :

**libraries\SymfonyHasherServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SymfonyHasherServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('hash', function()
        {
            return new SymfonyHasher;
        });
    }

}
```

Then, create your hasher, that will be a copy of Symfony hash method :

**libraries\SymfonyHasher.php**

```
class SymfonyHasher implements Illuminate\Hashing\HasherInterface {

    public function make($value, array $options = array())
    {
        /* make your hash here */
    }

    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = array())
    {
        return $hashedValue == $this->make($value);
    }

}
```

Replace **'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider'** with **'SymfonyHasherServiceProvider'** in the service providers array in **app.php config**, then add **'app/libraries'** to autoload classmap in composer.json

I don't know how Symfony make hashes, so you have to search how Symfony make hashes abd implement it as you need to do.

Comment: Could you please take me step by step on how i should do that?

Answer (score -1):

Formula:
**Hash::make(encryptFunc('password'))==Hash::make(encrypted_password);**

before Auth::attempt, set $userdata like:

```
$userdata = [
                'username'  => Input::get('username'),
                'password'  =>your_sha1_salt_function(Input::get('password'))

                ];
```

in your user.php

```
public function getAuthPassword()
    {

        return Hash::make($this->password);
    }
```

in Auth::attempt will do the Hash::check like:
 **Hash::check(your_sha1_salt_function(Input::get('password')),Hash::make($this->password))**

in this way, you will no need to create a new provider and change the configuration.